# Retroactive benefits cut

Tags: united-states, benefits

My company just announced that they will no longer award paid time off or sick leave, effective 15 days before the announcement. I’m concerned that such a change may not be legal.

I am paid monthly. The retroactive application date is the start of the current pay period.

I understand that no law requires granting paid time off (with a few exceptions).

Intuitively, it seems like it would be illegal for a company to say they decided to pay only 50% of the promised wages for time already worked. Does something similar apply to awarded time off?

Comment: You should ask this on Law, not here.  Also include your location as laws vary greatly by jurisdiction.